Issue with WatchFiles and FastAPI: Stuck Reloading and Port Conflicts
I'm encountering an issue with FastAPI where sometimes, when I use Ctrl+S to save changes, WatchFiles gets stuck on reloading. This causes the terminal to lag, and I can't exit or do anything else. The only way to resolve this is to forcefully close the terminal.
However, when I try to run the application on the same port afterward, it shows the old version of the application. I have to run the application on a different port, which is inconvenient and impractical.
Is there a way to resolve this issue, or if not, how can I release the old port? I can see the port in netstat, but the PID is not findable in Windows Task Manager.
Steps to Reproduce:
Use Ctrl+S to save changes in a FastAPI project.
Observe that WatchFiles sometimes gets stuck reloading, causing the terminal to lag.
Expected Behavior:
The application should reload without getting stuck, and the terminal should remain responsive.
Actual Behavior:
WatchFiles gets stuck on reloading, the terminal lags, and the only way to continue is to forcefully close the terminal.
Environment:
FastAPI version: 0.0.4
WatchFiles version: 0.22.0
Operating System: Windows
Code Example:
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
  return {"Hello": "World"}

Additional Context:
If the port is occupied, I can see it in netstat, but the PID is not findable in Windows Task Manager.

This is an issue in PyCharm: https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/2000 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60962/os.killpid-signal.CRTLCEVENT-ignored-when-running-python-program-from-Pycharm

I still have this problem but what I can do for now is close the terminal and run again on different port using this command:
uvicorn main:app --reload --port 80


op never talks about uvicorn?
